# how to stop Batch script for loop adding newlines in string variable spaces?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, newline

```
echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /p "short_description=description:"
if not defined short_description set "short_description={short_description}"
set /p "entry_point=entry point: (index.js)"
if not defined entry_point set "entry_point=index.js"

`for %%I in (
    "{"
    "  "description": "%short_description%","
    "  "main": "%entry_point%","
    "}"
) do (
if %%I=="." (
        echo.>> "package.json"
    ) else (
        echo %%~I>> "package.json"
    )
)
```

when the prompt variable text has spaces in it the output ends up having newlines in each space character of the variable string.

Here is an example:
This is the prompts with my test response:

```
description:description with spaces in the text
entry point: (index.js)index.html
```

this is the output

```
{
  "description": "description
with
spaces
in
the
text","
  "main": "index.html",
}
```

it should look like this:

```
{
  "description": "description with spaces in the text",
  "main": "index.html",
}
```